# WPF DatePicker Watermark uses wrong Language, but the Dateformat is correct

Tags: c#, wpf, internationalization, datepicker

I have a very strange Problem:

On my machine the DatePicker changes its watermark AND date-format according to the language/culture i want to set.

If i copy my application to other computers following happens:

On some computer it works like it does on my machine. On other computers only the date-format changes but the watermark does not! Needless to say it is very ugly to have a datepicker with e.g. a german date but an english watermark.

**What is the cause for that behaviour?**

For i18n i use following code:

App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); 
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    }
}
```

WindowMain.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class WindowMain : RibbonWindow
{
    public WindowMain()
    {
        this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("de-DE");
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing I can say, `Watermark` in `DatePicker` implemented buggy, there is no easy access. Perhaps, because of this difficulty, the localization of the text does not work. There is a wonderful article of `@Matt Hamilton`, quote from [here](http://matthamilton.net/datepicker-watermark):

> Something that a lot of people (myself included) don't like about the DatePicker, though, is that by default if no date is displayed it shows the text "Select a date" as a watermark, and this text is baked into the control - it's not localized or accessible by any public property. This is particularly frustrating if the date in question is optional and you don't necessarily want to prompt your users to select one.

In the same article, he provide the decision of how to access to `Watermark`. Here:

[How to localize the WPF 4.0 DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672258/how-to-localize-the-wpf-4-0-datepicker-control)

`@Wayne Maurer` created a universal solution in the form of *attached* dependency property:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="2" 
            local:DatePickerWatermarkBehaviour.Watermark="Select the date" />
```

You need to be based on the current culture, set the text for watermarks, e.g. using above example.

`Note:` In Silverlight to `Watermark` in `DatePicker` made access [[`link`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/05/06/changing-the-watermark-text-in-a-datepicker-control.aspx)]:

```
DatePickerTextBox box = base.GetTemplateChild("TextBox") as DatePickerTextBox;
box.Watermark = "Type or select a date --> ";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its quite informative, however it does not explain why the localization actualy works on some machines. That is confusing me.

Comment: @M C: Yes, I agree that's weird. On machines which have an operating system? They are the same OS or different?

Comment: 2 machines have WinXP 2 machines Win7. 1 win xp and 1 win7 machine works. the others dont. so its not the OS. But both working machines got Visual Studio on them. Mine got VS2012 pro the other one VS2010 express. Is it possible that i forgot to copy some assemblies to the user computers, since it works on developer machines? If yes: which ones?

Comment: ok its also not the Visual Studio. Just tried another machine, a Terminal Server on Win2008R2. There it works like charm!

Comment: @M C: I think the properly just say the developers of `DatePicker`. I suspect that in the case of different operating systems. For universal solutions I propose to do the setting of the text in a `Watermark` via attached dependency property or most to make `DatePicker` control, because it is the `Button` (open `Calendar`) with the `TextBox`.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help. If i (ever) discover what makes the datepicker localization work/fail on specific computers i'll post it here.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually really easy to set the watermarked text:

```
<DatePicker>
  <DatePicker.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
      <Setter Property="Text" Value="Watermark Text"/>
    </Style>
  </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

http://www.admindiaries.com/change-datepicker-watermark-in-wpf/

Comment: Awesome! Any idea how to change the text color? Foreground doesn't work.

Comment: This does not change the water mark, it actually sets the text. It results in a different behavior when entering a date into the control with the keyboard.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you set a date and then delete it, the old watermark text is used again.

Answer (score 3):

Wayne solution works great but does not work when DatePicker is part of DataGridColumnHeader and sometimes when DatePicker is on control that is first hidden and then visible. Matt Hamilton's solution works only onLoad, and when you change selectedDate there is again annoying Select a date watermark. The easiest solution is just to override OnRender event in custom class. If you set watermark property and not a watermark content that you need to override onload event as well. Complete class is here:

```
public class myDateTimePicker : DatePicker
{

    public string Watermark { get; set; }

    protected override void OnSelectedDateChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedDateChanged(e);
        //SetWatermark();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        SetWatermark();
    }

    private void SetWatermark()
    {
        FieldInfo fiTextBox = typeof(DatePicker).GetField("_textBox", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (fiTextBox != null)
        {
            DatePickerTextBox dateTextBox = (DatePickerTextBox)fiTextBox.GetValue(this);
            if (dateTextBox != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Watermark))
                {
                    this.Watermark = "Custom watermark";
                }

                // if you set property this way then you need to override OnSelectedDateChanged event
                //PropertyInfo piWatermark = typeof(DatePickerTextBox).GetProperty("Watermark", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                //if (piWatermark != null)
                //{
                //    piWatermark.SetValue(dateTextBox, this.Watermark, null);
                //}

                var partWatermark = dateTextBox.Template.FindName("PART_Watermark", dateTextBox) as ContentControl;
                if (partWatermark != null)
                {
                    partWatermark.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                    partWatermark.Content = this.Watermark;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```